# Calling a callback function alone?

Tags: python, callback, tornado

I have this code (tries to test internet connection with a non-blocking call):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
a = ''

def on_g(response):
    if response.error:
        on_b()
    else:
        global a        
        a = response.body
        return True

http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", on_g)

def on_b(response):
    if response.error:
        return False
    else:
        return True
http_client.fetch("http://www.baidu.com/", on_b)
```

How can i call `on_g()` or `on_b()` for debug purpose? because it needs an argument which is the `response`.

Comment: i want to check if it returns True or false when i execute it on the console

Comment: Also don't use globals. They are especially bad practice when you're doing asynchronous callbacks. You'll never be able to guarantee *which* body you'll see in `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing, you could always mock the parameter with a simple wrapper around `dict`; for example:

```
class Mock(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self[key]


on_b(Mock({    
    'error': False,
    'body': 'Mock body',
}))
```

And then check if the return value/changes in global state match your expectations.

Creating exactly the same `response` object as Tornado is not necessary, since Python does [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Passing a mock object where you're 100% sure of what the various parameters are is often *better* for testing, since it's much more transparent.

There are larger libraries (such as [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/)) that you'll probably want to use if you're doing this more often than a handful of times; but this should work okay for quick testing, or just a few simple tests.

Comment: I don't believe this example will work since a `dict` doesn't expose the values via attribute access.

Comment: @b4hand Thank you. You are completely right. I got confused since I've been doing a lot of CoffeeScript today... A simple wrapper fixes this, I've updated the answer).

Comment: it worked like a charm, thank you! here is the screenshot
http://imgur.com/W8DquUe

Comment: @Abdelouahab You don't need to re-define the class; defining it once and then creating several instances of it is fine.

Comment: ah, thank you :) and if someone comes here from searching how to `mock` i found this wonderful video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XiArCSZc3g

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to mock the response object. I've done this using tornado previously, and it works just fine. This also gives you the control that you can test arbitrary responses that you would not otherwise be able to reproduce easily. I recommend the [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) package, but you can also do it by hand.

Here's an example using the `mock` package:

```
from mock import Mock
on_b(Mock(error=False, body='body'))
```

Here's an example by hand:

```
class Mock(object):
    pass
mock = Mock()
mock.error = False
mock.body = 'body'
on_b(mock)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking but the callback functions are just functions, and can be called like any other python function

`on_g(some_object)`

`on_b(some_object)`

You could import them and call them in tests.

Comment: the problem is about the `some_object` how to generate it

Comment: @Abdelouahab you could mock it, or I think you could import tornado's http client from the command line and just execute it, using an example like http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.4/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient

Comment: @dm03512 as current tornado, you can execute the code without calling the `IOLoop`